# Setup custom Prometheus metric with Kubernetes labels for TorchServe

Tags: python, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, torchserve

I'm trying to setup `http_request_duration_seconds` metric the same as provides [`prometheus-net`](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/blob/60e9106a83ff1274fec0022c37366f04822b1d1b/Prometheus.AspNetCore/HttpMetrics/HttpRequestDurationMiddleware.cs#L37)

.NET implementation somehow adds dimensions like `namespace`, `service`, `pod`, and `code` that could be used in Grafana:

```
// ...
"targets": [
  {
    "datasource": {
      "type": "prometheus",
      "uid": "${datasource}"
    },
    "exemplar": true,
    "expr": "sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count{namespace=\"$namespace\", service=~\"$service\", pod=~\"$pod\"}[$interval])) by (code)",
    "interval": "",
    "legendFormat": "{{ code }}",
    "queryType": "randomWalk",
    "refId": "A"
  }
],
"title": "Requests per second",
"type": "timeseries"
// ...
```

It seems like I could extract these values from context. I've read [the article related to k8s and TorchServe](https://github.com/pytorch/serve/tree/master/kubernetes#readme) and didn't find anything related to my problem.

A piece of code related to the metric:

```
http_request_duration_seconds_count = self.metrics.get_metric(
    metric_name='http_request_duration_seconds',
    metric_type=MetricTypes.HISTOGRAM)
start = time.monotonic()

request = data[0]
dataset = self.preprocess(request)
inferenced = self.inference(dataset)
result = self.postprocess(inferenced)

http_request_duration_seconds_count.add_or_update(
    value=time.monotonic() - start,
    # dimension_values=['namespace_name', 'service_service', 'pod_name']
)
emit_metrics(self.metrics.store)
```